# Correct way of returning iOS UILabel method

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am creating a UILabel in a method called displayTemp

```
- (UILabel *) displayTemp
{
_tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 240, 300, 30)];
[self.view addSubview:_tempLabel];

NSDictionary *key = [self.getAPICall objectForKey:@"currently"];

_tempLabel.text = [key objectForKey:@"temperature"];

return _tempLabel;
}
```

This is simply just bringing back a value from an API call.

I then want to show dis UILabel and its text in the viewDidLoad method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.976 green:0.518 blue:0.439 alpha:1];

UILabel *getTemp = self.displayTemp;
//How do I return the text property of self.DisplayTemp
}
```

How would I then return this? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing idioms here.  Instead of doing this "`@property`" type thing:

```
UILabel *getTemp = self.displayTemp;
```

Change that line to this:

```
[self displayTemp];
```

in your "`viewDidLoad`" method and you'll be okay. You don't need to return a UILabel object from the displayTemp method because you're already adding it to your view controller's view.

Comment: Ah right yes I understand. When I run the app now I get this exception: unrecognized selector sent to instance Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x917de20'

Comment: That's coming from a different part of your code.  I don't see the word "`length`" in the code snippet that you put in your question.  It looks like you are trying to get the string length of an object that's really a "`NSNumber`" object.

Comment: Oh yes of course, I know what it is. Brilliant thanks for your help.

Comment: That `length` error is coming from passing a `NSNumber` to the `text` property of `UILabel`, which calls length internally.

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *getTemp = [self displayTemp];

getTemp.text
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition @MichaelDautermann's answer, I suggest you to create UILabel just one time in `-(UILabel *)displayTemp` method with conditional branch(if). Although the method would be called just one time since it is called by `-(void)viewDidLoad`, in terms of architecture of class, you would better make the method more flexible and safe against multiple calls.

Therefore, I modified the method as follow:

```
- (UILabel *) displayTemp
{
   if (_tempLabel == nil) {
       _tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 240, 300, 30)];
       NSDictionary *key = [self.getAPICall objectForKey:@"currently"];
      _tempLabel.text = [key objectForKey:@"temperature"];
       [self.view addSubview:_tempLabel];
   }

  return _tempLabel;
}
```

I hope that my suggestion will be useful for you.